# Is there a way I can develop and test Map reduce program on windows development box

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I would like to develop and test Map reduce program on windows 7 machine before deploying to Hadoop cluster.

If it is possible, can any body point me to some good resources.

I have eclipse installed on my windows machine, what else i need to develop and test map reduce program.

Comment: Personally I'd consider a VM or buying another machine with a real OS. http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can test localy with MRUnit http://mrunit.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Linux is the only OS supported for production. I don't know whether you can install Hadoop on Windows or not (I never tried that) but I would suggest to go with a "Hadoop Distribution".

You can for example get a VirtualBox image from HortonWorks or Cloudera (major Hadoop players) and run it on your Windows machine (for development and testing purposes).

The distribution usually include the Hadoop ecosystem: Hadoop, HDFS, Pig, Hive, HCatalog, Impala ...

Everything is configured to be compatible with each other (real time saver).

Comment: I have Hortonworks VM installed. I didn't find any thing there for MR development, even for some basic operations also I am using putty. I don't know how can i develop and test MR in Hortonworks VM.

Comment: Huh? HortonWorks comes with every infrastructure you need to run your Hadoop jobs, Pig jobs, Hive queries.

Comment: i will appreciate if you can provide some pointers for developing MR code on Horton works VM. I spent some time goggling to my luck didn't find any thing useful.

Comment: For example http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/#tutorial_gallery and http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/loading-data-into-the-hortonworks-sandbox/

Comment: Of course you can, read more about Hadoop in general and then you will  understand what those VM are doing for you.